# Recursive call of TreeRelation in stored procedure raises cursor error 'already in use'

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql

I have created a simple tree relation in postgres. A father node can have n-nodes. To get all childs from a father node I want to write a stored procedure that calls itself recursivly. This is the point where I am stuck.

My idea was that I call the procedure with the father node, then I get all its childs, call for every child the procedure again. The recursive step, the calling of the method, seems to kill the procedure but I can't tell why.

Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE treeDown(INTEGER)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
    cur_childs CURSOR FOR select * from TreeRelation where von = $1 AND from < to;
    rec RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN cur_childs LOOP
        CALL treeDown(rec.to); -- seems to die here
        RAISE NOTICE '% is a child from %', rec.to, $1;
    end loop;
END;
$$;
```

Error message:

> [42P03] ERROR: cursor "cur_childs" already in use 
>   Wobei: PL/pgSQL
>   function treedown(integer) line 6 at FOR over cursor SQL statement
>   "CALL treeDown(rec.nach)" PL/pgSQL function treedown(integer) line 7
>   at CALL

Any ideas? Am I executing the call correctly or is there a different way to call a stored procedure in a stored procedure.

Comment: Looks like something you could do with a recursive CTE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a named cursor, you can use an anonymous cursor, so there's no need to reuse the already existing one.

```
...
FOR rec IN (SELECT *
                   FROM treerelation
                   WHERE ...) LOOP
...
```

Comment: works perfectly, thank you. Maybe you could explain to me why this error occures with named cursor but works with anonymous cursor?

Answer (score 0):

I also found a working way using `WITH RECURSIVE`:

```
-- 3 is our start node in this case
WITH RECURSIVE test(s) AS (
            select to from TreeRelation where from = 3 AND from < to
        UNION
            select to from test, TreeRelation where from = test.s AND from < to
        ) select * from test;
```

What did I learn? `WITH RECURSIVE` always has `1 non-recursive select` and `1 recursive select`. The recursive select is able to access the data from our temporary table `test` which is filled by our non-recursive select. The recursive function (the 2nd select) is called for every entry `test` gets from the non-recursive select (the 1st one).